# PHP create datetime with specific day each mounth between 2 dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to create a date-time with specific day each month between a start date and a end date.
Example :

- Specific day : 04
- Start : 2016-12-22
- End : 2017-03-06
- Output needed : 2016-01-04 ; 2016-02-04 ; 2016-03-04

How can I do that?

Comment: If you've found the answer, then why you've posted the question here..!!!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi In general lines, there's nothing wrong in posting a question with the only intention of answering it.

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I posted the question because I have long checked the answer without finding it. By dint of trying I got there on my own. I thought that since I had not found the solution on the web I was going to post it for future developers who would look for the solution

Comment: @AntoineSubit - I got it, great, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object and iterate over it to get all the dates you need:

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-12-22');
$end   = new DateTime('2017-03-06');

// Compute the occurrence on the same month as $start
$first = new DateTime();
$first->setDate($start->format('Y'), $start->format('m'), 4);

// If it is in the past of $start then the first occurrence is on the next month
if ($first < $start) {
    $first->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}

// Create a DatePeriod object that iterates between $first and $end
// in increments of 1 month
$period = new DatePeriod($first, new DateInterval('P1M'), $end);

// Run through the list, process each item
foreach ($period as $day) {
    echo($day->format('Y-m-d')."\n");
}
```